# Puppet: Run in noop mode except for the first time

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I am trying to figure out how to run a Puppet configuration on a newly bootstrapped node, and then, from then onwards, only run as noop in order to collect reports on infrastructure changes / drifts.

So... let's say I have this simple manifest:

```
node puppeta1, puppeta2 {    
  file { "/var/tmp/testfile2":
    noop => true,
    ensure => "present",
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    mode => "664",
    content => "This is a test file created using puppet.
                Puppet is really cool",
  }

..
```

In this case, I only want to have the `/var/tmp/testfile2` file created the first time when the `puppeta1` and `puppeta2` nodes are created. From then onwards, I just want to run it in noop mode to detect whether the file was modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally keep your resource declarations as they are without `noop`, and run Puppet out-of-band using `puppet apply` or `puppet agent` on-boot, then configure the Puppet system service to use `--noop` by editing `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[agent]
noop = true
```

Or, disable the system service entirely, and add `--noop` to your cron entry.

Reference: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/configuration.html#noop

Answer (score 1):

With the `file` resource type, would adding `replace => false` achieve what you need? Then Puppet will create the file if it's missing, but won't overwrite any possible changed made to that file if the file contents have been changed afterwards.

Comment: This works for new files, but what about more critical configuration files such as `/etc/hosts` and similar files that already exist in the system?

Comment: @JamesJ. Puppet won't log changes, even in noop, for files it does not manage. Are you sure you don't want to use [something like AIDE](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using-aide)? That's fine if you also have file resources for `/etc/hosts`, etc. But your comment reads like maybe not.